# RESTful client in c

Tags: c, http, restful-url

Hi I want to make RESTful call to remote sever.
url is http://bulksms.net/API.svc/sms/json/sendmessage?username=newuser&password=newpasswd&msg=test&msisdn=9999999999&tagname=Demo&shortcode=8888&telcoId=5&dnRequired=false
The server document says:

```
Parameters
```

string username, string password, string msg, string msisdn, string tagname, string shortcode, int telcoId, bool dnRequired

Return Value
API will return and object containing three members
IsSuccess 
Message
UniqueId

I have made a sample client in c but its not working. below is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CURL *curl;
  char url[80];
  CURLcode res;

  strcpy(url,"http://bulksms.net/API.svc/sms/json/sendmessage?username=newuser&password=newpasswd&msg=test&msisdn=9999999999&tagname=Demo&shortcode=8888&telcoId=5&");

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, url);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output :

Comment: msd the output to write <BODY><h2>Length Required</h2> <hr><p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p>

Comment: Fyi, that string is **far** beyond 80 chars (its more like 150 including the terminator). As such, your `strcpy` invokes undefined behavior and your program is ill-formed

Comment: or even better - `strdup` (remember to free the result though)

Comment: changed the indexed array to char url[] but the error remain same ----<hr><p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p> . I think I have to add something related to RESTfull

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the problem. Actually in RESTful POST method url and data should be added part by part. below is the successfull client in c for RESTfull POST method.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  char url[]= "http://bulksms.net/API.svc/sms/json/sendmessage";
  char postData[] = "username=newuser&password=newpasswd&msg=test&msisdn=9999999999&tagname=Demo&shortcode=8888&telcoId=5&dnRequired=false";
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postData);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `strcpy` function cause undefined behavior because you have buffer of 80 char and source string is more then it.

Try something like this.

```
char url[]="http://bulksms.net/API.svc/sms/json/sendmessage?username=newuser&password=newpasswd&msg=test&msisdn=9999999999&tagname=Demo&shortcode=8888&telcoId=5&";
```

You can use [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) or [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) for safe copy and avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: removed indexed array and used char url[], but that didnt stoped the error. ---- <hr><p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p>

Comment: @JYOTIRANJANPANDA: Pay attention to that error message. Your request either needs to be chunked or have a content length set...

Answer (score 0):

Unlike SOAP-based web services, there is no "official" standard for RESTful web APIs. This is because REST is an architectural style, while SOAP is a protocol. Even though REST is not a standard per se, most RESTful implementations make use of standards such as HTTP, URI, JSON, and XML.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a belated answer, but there is a complete and awesome library to allow you introduce your restful api via C/C++. Works on Linux, Freebsd, and Windows (probably more operating systems as well)

The github https://github.com/babelouest/ulfius